# Jenkins - how to maintain views generated manually and by Process Job DSLs plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I would like to ask if there is a way to keep in one, main view other views that part of them are generated by "Process Job DSLs" plugin and others are created manually? Currently I have view called "Main View". Inside "Main View" I have few views ("Production", "Test", "Verify") generated by groovy script. I wanted to add manually new view "Adaptation" into "Main View". Unfortunately once I created "Adaptation" view manually  it has been removed after I run groovy script (groovy script is located in Jenkins job in "Process Job DSLs" build step). I tried to mark "Ignore changes" inside Jenkins job and it helped to prevent removing manually created view but now "Main View" is not updated when I want to create new view using groovy script. Is there any other option that allows to keep views created manually and automatically all together?

Problem description:

- Views inside "Main View" are generated by groovy script from "Process Job DSLs" build step in jenkins job
- I want to add manually new view inside "Main View"
- Newly, manually added view is being removed once I run Jenkins job
- "Ignore changes" options allows to remain manually created view but it also prevents from creating new views by Jenkins job
- I want to be able to keep both manually and automatically views inside main view